# Reducer don't know my state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to write an app, where the user can add an item to the collection. The user types the name of collection-item and the item with this name occurs.
But when i dispatch action `addCollection` :

```
export function addCollection(text) {
    console.log("ACTION ADD COLLECTION FIRED");
    return {
        type: "ADD_COLLECTION",
        text
    }
}
```

to my reducer :

```
export default function collection(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_COLLECTION":
        return (
            Object.assign({}, state, {
                 collections: [
                    {
                        name: action.text,
                        src:''
                    },
                    ...state.collections
                ]
            })
        );

    }
    return state
}
```

ERROR OCCURED :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

It comes to line 6 in my reducer. I think reducer don't know my state.collection

```
var initialState = {
    collections:[
        {
            name:"Aenean in justo ante",
            src: ''
        },
        {
            name:"Aenean in justo ante",
            src: ''
        }
    ],
    formIsRender: false
}

const store = createStore(allReducers, initialState)
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial state is an `array` not an `object`.
You can't and shouldn't use `Object.assign` on arrays.
You can use though the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in order to not mutate the array.

Try this instead:

```
 case "ADD_COLLECTION":
        return [...state, {name: action.text}]
```

Another thing i've noticed is that in your initial state object you named it `collections` (plural) and your reducer's name is `collection` (singular).
Make sure it's not a typo.